# One Image into Different Social links

Tags: html, css

I found this method of making one image featuring different social icons on it into different social links by using x and y icons to define the section of the image you want featured in a link.

The issue I'm having is that once I set up the code, the background image isn't showing up. If anyone could offer their insight into why this code isn't working as it shoul, it would be greatly appreciated!

CSS:

```
aside .social {
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.social ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
}
.social li {
    display: block;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    margin: 0 4px 6px 0;
    display:-moz-inline-stack;
    display:inline-block;
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;
    line-height: 20px;
}
.social li:nth-child(8n+0) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.social li a, .social li a:active, .social li a:visited {
    opacity: 0.5;
    -moz-transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
}
.social li a:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.social li.facebook a { background: url(http://static.tumblr.com/csqo1yp/4uimntnjk/social.png) 0 0; }
.social li.twitter a { background: url(http://static.tumblr.com/csqo1yp/4uimntnjk/social.png) -24px 0; }
.social li.youtube a { background: url(http://static.tumblr.com/csqo1yp/4uimntnjk/social.png) -48px 0; }
.social li.instagram a { background: url(http://static.tumblr.com/csqo1yp/4uimntnjk/social.png) -72px 0; }
.social li.google a { background: url(http://static.tumblr.com/csqo1yp/4uimntnjk/social.png) -96px 0; }
.social li.flickr a { background: url(http://static.tumblr.com/csqo1yp/4uimntnjk/social.png) -120px 0; }
.social li.linkedin a { background: url(http://static.tumblr.com/csqo1yp/4uimntnjk/social.png) -144px 0; }
```

HTML:

```
<h1>Find Us On</h1>
    <div class="social">
        <ul>
            <li class="facebook"><a href="{text:Facebook URL}" target="_blank"></a></li>
            <li class="twitter"><a href="http://www.twitter.com/{text:Twitter Username}" target="_blank"></a></li>
            <li class="youtube"><a href="{text:YouTube URL}" target="_blank"></a></li>
            <li class="google"><a href="{text:Google Plus URL}" target="_blank"></a></li>
            <li class="instagram"><a href="http://www.instagram.com/{text:Instagram Username}" target="_blank"></a></li>
            <li class="flickr"><a href="{text:Flickr URL}" target="_blank"></a></li>
            <li class="linkedin"><a href="{text:Linkdin URL}" target="_blank"></a></li>
        </ul>
    <div>
```

I have also created a JSFiddle for your convenience here: http://jsfiddle.net/HRHnY/

The code is rendering the list, it's just the background image isn't displaying...

Comment: The method you're talking about using is called Spriting / Sprites.

Comment: Ahhh! I thought there was probably a proper term for the method! Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your anchors are collapsing to 0x0 because you have no content in them.  They don't auto-expand to the size of the parent just because you have a background image.  Explicitly give them a width/height like the li and you get http://jsfiddle.net/HRHnY/2/

Relevant CSS for the anchors:

```
display: block;
width: 24px;
height: 24px;
```

Alternatively you could set width and height to 100% of the parent instead of explicitly setting it.

Comment: Aaaah... I see. I thought the width and height properties in the initial .social li class would carry over to the links... but lesson learned! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HRHnY/7/)**

The `a` elements, are `inline` and the `width` and `height` of them,
is calculated by the data within them.
So you must set them explicitly, add this rule to your CSS:

```
.social a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
}
```

---

### TIP

It's better to write `background-image` only once in general selector:

```
.social a {
    background: url(http://static.tumblr.com/csqo1yp/4uimntnjk/social.png);
}
```

And just change `background-position` for each element:

```
.social li.facebook a {
    background-position: 0 0;
}

.social li.twitter a {
    background-position: -24px 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining that to me! And that is a useful tip! I will fix that right now!